# OutOfMemoryError in StringBuilder.append() even with more than enough memory

Tags: java, out-of-memory, stringbuilder

I get an OutOfMemoryError from java.lang.StringBuilder.append even when I set the memory size to 32 GB and reading only a 500 MB file into the builder.

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: null
    at java.base/java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.hugeCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:214) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.newCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:206) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:173) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:538) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:174) ~[na:na]
    at com.github.loa.indexer.service.index.base64.Base64Encoder.encode(Base64Encoder.java:31) ~[classes/:na]
```

Comment: It would be great do add code snippet to get more context as to what is happening.

Comment: My use case is quite complex. Trying to stream a file into byte arrays in 3072-byte long chunks, then encode the chunks with java.util.Base64, append the result of the encoding to a StringBuilder. Sadly the StringBuilder dies quickly. I need to get the whole base64 string into the memory to send it to Elasticsearch (streaming is not an option). The code is available here: https://github.com/bottomless-archive-project/library-of-alexandria/blob/f3e604b2477e512939d9a134b79bfd38b51ff1c1/loa-service/loa-indexer-service/src/main/java/com/github/loa/indexer/service/index/base64/Base64Encoder.java

Comment: What version of Java are you running?

Comment: @Andreas Java 11. I think it specific to Java 9+ but not sure.

Comment: Kinda sloppy that they throw an OOM. Now I need to catch it somewhere in my code and I know, catching OOMs are quite bad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because the byte array that the StringBuilder want to allocate would require a larger array size than allowed by the JVM (more than 2147483647 aka Integer.MAX_VALUE elements).

Comment: Said another way, it's a limit of Java that strings cannot exceed 2 GB in size, which generally means that it cannot exceed 1 billion characters (latin1-only strings can be 2 billion characters in later versions of Java).